# Using gnu toolchain compiled library in Keil

Tags: c, arm, keil, newlib, gnu-toolchain

I'm trying to use a library I compiled under `debian` by `GNU toolchain` in `Keil` and getting this error:

> ._build\nrf52832_xxaa_s132.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol
>   _impure_ptr

this symbol comes from `newlib`, How can I compile a library with `arm-none-eabi-gcc` without `newlib`?

I've already tried `-nostdlib` but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can't. That's why the error is showing up.

Comment: your library uses some glibc functions. They require reentrancy.

Comment: Ok. Seems there is no way to handle this. Thx